# Last value only being fetched in drop down Laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, php-5.6

> I'm using Laravel 5. I wanted to list all the database names in
>   dropdown, but I always end up fetching the last value. I already use
>   foreach loop, still nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
public function create(Request $request)
    {
        //echo "<pre>";
        $sqlconn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '1234');
        $showdb = "SHOW DATABASES";
        $dbconn = mysqli_query($sqlconn, $showdb);
        $dbnames = array();


        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbconn)) {
                 $dbnames = $row;
                 foreach ($dbnames as $dbname => $value) {
                    if ($value != "information_schema" && $value != "performance_schema" && $value != "test" && $value != "mysql") {
                        //$dblists = implode(":", array($value));
                        $dblists = $value;
                        //print_r($dblists);
                    }
                 }
        }

        //die();
}

And here's my html codes:

<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group @if($errors->has('description')) has-error @endif">
                      <div class="col-xs-2">
                          <label for="reports_description" class="control-label"><h5><b>Select Database:</b></h5></label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-5">
                          <select class="form-control">
                            <option>---SELECT---</option>
                            <option value="{{$dblists}}">{{$dblists}}</option>
                          </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>  
                  </div>
```

Comment: Two things to note for you - 1. You are initializing `$dblists` as a variable not an array 2. `$dblists` is being initialized inside the foreach loop - hence it will contain only the `$value` from the last iteration of the loop. You should initialize the `$dblists=[];` out of the foreach loop and then within the `if` condition in the foreach loop `$dblists[] = $value` will keep pushing the values into `$dblists` array;

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
   $databases = \DB::select('show databases');

   return view('view.name', compact('databases'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($databases as $database)
  <p>{{ $database->Database }}<p>
@endforeach
```